# Magento 1.7 - wrong currency symbol

Tags: php, magento, currency

I want to display different currencies in my multistore. For Euro in germany and US-Dollar in US it is working fine. Now i try to show australien dollars in AU-shop but it won't work.

- Localisation is set to: English (US)
- Currency setup ist set to: Australian Dollar, and Australian Dollar is allowed as currency.

But in frontend prices are shown in euro.
If i change currency setup to US-Dollar, it is working fine and prices are shown with $ in front.

I read about modifying some *.xml in lib/Zend/Locale/Data but i don't know which one is the right one to modify. 
In en_AU is:

```
<currency type="AUD">
    <symbol>$</symbol>
</currency>
```

in root.xml:

```
<currency type="AUD">
    <symbol>AU$</symbol>
</currency>
```

I found many pages on google with many modification hints, but none of them is working yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
there was no currency rate configured for Australian Dollars.
You can configure it under: **System->Currency Configuration->Currency rates**.

(I use german backend language, so i don't know the exact naming in english backend)